# How to skip installing extra software during the installation by using batch script

Tags: command-line, windows-installer

I am trying to remotely install software by using a batch file and `psexec`. During the installation process it asks me to install extra software which I don't need. If I don't install this extra software the whole install process will hang forever.

the switches i use :
`setup.exe /S /v /qn`

This will hang up on the installation of the extra software in that setup.exe package
How do I skip installing the extra software?

Comment: What's that `\\drive1\etc` command line?  Is that the step you want to skip?  Can you not just delete it from the batch file?  I'm afraid I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: everything before .exe is the path to install.exe. i will make it short

Comment: But I don't understand what that .exe has to do with your question.

Comment: Reading between the lines (including in the full path of the exe from earlier revisions of the question) - the OP is running that setup.exe which is a PowerShape installer, on a remote PC (using psexec). The powershape installer is trying to install something else (from googling, probably the VC Redistributable package). This secondary install is failing. OP, there's a mention of this problem here: http://forum.delcam.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=9501&sid=5eeeb849259a96007b55d0c1ae58d733

Comment: @USER Things that you need to know: 1- Exists different kinds of "setups.exe" (Setup builders) and not all have the same switches. 2 - Setups have their packages, so you need to found the package name. 3- You are using a MSI setup installer so you can use the switch to install only the desired packages. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx 4- your question have any relation with Batch files.

Comment: thanks for replay.

I just found out that the installer does not support the "skip" thing. silent installation for  this version of software can not be performed. it has been fixed on 2013 version.

Answer (score 1):

Setup.exe /s /v /qn  indicates an InstallShield setup.exe. On a clean (virtual) machine:

1. Navigate to %TEMP% and clean it out
2. Run the setup.exe interactively
3. Look in %TEMP% for GUID directories to grab the installer.

Now you should have a FOO.MSI file.  Use the commandline:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi REBOOT=R /qn
```

To install it.  Realize that the MSI might have additional checks to make sure that the list of prerequistes that setup.exe was going to install are in fact installed.  You'll have to figure out how to get each of these on the machine via psexec.  It's not as simple as it sounds since you are basically decomposing setup.exe and reimplementing it.

BTW, this question is off topic since you aren't developing the installer you are trying to install someone elses.